# How to set start date in 2amigos Datepicker in Yii2

Tags: jquery, datepicker, yii2

I want to set start date in 2amigos Datepicker using jQuery or whatever it is.

My start date is `1960-01-01`.

And this is my how I display Datepicker:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'ecs_cheque_dd_date')->widget(DatePicker::className(), [
    'inline' => false, 
    'clientOptions' => [
        'autoclose' => true,
        'format' => 'yyyy-m-dd',
    ],
]) ?>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'ecs_cheque_dd_date')->widget(DatePicker::className(), [
    'inline' => false, 
    'clientOptions' => [
        'autoclose' => true,
        'format' => 'yyyy-mm-dd',
        'startDate' => date('1960-01-01'),
    ],
]) ?>
```

Comment: how  can i add date after 1 month from curent date.

Answer (score 1):

Just open dosamigos\datetimepicker\DateTimePicker and read phpDoc:

> Please refer to the Bootstrap DatePicker plugin Web page for possible options.
>
> @see http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/release/options.html

Your answer is probably:

> "startDate" Beginning of time
>
> The earliest date that may be selected; all earlier dates will be disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one...
add this:

```
use dosamigos\datepicker\DatePicker;


<?= $form->field($model, 'startdate')->widget(DatePicker::classname(), [
                        'clientOptions' => [
                                'format' => 'yyyy-mm-dd'
                               ],
                    ]).DatePicker::widget([
                    'attribute' => 'end_date',
                            'name' => 'DATE',
                            'value' => 'enddate',
                        'clientOptions' => [
                                'format' => 'yyyy-mm-dd'
                               ],
                    ]) ?>
```

Answer (score -2):

Finally I found answer

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'ecs_cheque_dd_date')->widget(DatePicker::className(), [
    'inline' => false, 
    'clientOptions' => [
        'autoclose' => true,
        'format' => 'yyyy-m-dd',
        'startDate' => date('1960-01-01'),
        'endDate' => date(''),
    ],
]) ?>
```